# Перебор Подмножеств

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте мне нужно написать код на си++,перебор всех подмножеств данного множества
Но у меня перебор идет следующим образом:Допустим есть множество 4-х элементов {1,2,3,4},выводиться подмножества будут так {1},{2},{1,2},{3},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3} и т.д.
А мне же надо,чтобы они выводились следующим образом {1},{2},{3},{4},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2,4} и т.д. Хотел бы попросить помощи.Вот как писал я

```
#include "conio.h"

#include "locale.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "iostream"

 using namespace std;

 void main()
{
int s;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
cout << "Выбирете тип вводимого элемента: \n1 - тип int; 2 - тип char" << endl;
cin >> s;
switch(s)
{
case 1:

    int a[10], x, k;
    cout << "Введите кол-во элементов типа int: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Введите элементы: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
    cin >> a[i];
    cout << endl;
    k=powf(2,x);
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++) 
        {
            cout << "{";
            for (int j=0; j<x; j++) 
                if (i & (1<<j))
                 cout << a[j] << " "; 
                 cout << "}" << endl;
        }
break;

case 2:

    char b[10]; 
    int y, z;
    cout << "Введите кол-во элементов типа char: " << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Введите элементы: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<y; i++)
    {
    cin >> b[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    z=powf(2,y);
    for (int i=0; i<z; i++) 
        {
            cout << "{";
            for (int j=0; j<y; j++) 
                if (i & (1<<j))
                 cout << b[j] << " "; 
                 cout << "}" << endl;
        }
break;

default: printf("Error"); break;
}

_getch();
```

}

Comment: А иероглифы могут быть? Китайские или тайские? А вообще всё очень просто: отображаете свои элементы на n-тиричную (и как это называется) систему счисления, и далее отображаете последовательность чисел от 1 до максимума. Недействительные комбинации (например два и более одинаковых элементов, нуль не в начале) -- пропускаете.

Comment: Alexzl,в смысле?просто перебор чисел но не так как у меня,а как я написал выше

Comment: как говорите вы сложно.можно ли это сделать в несколько циклов?

Answer (score 2):

[@ivan145](/users/16874/ivan145)

> как говорите вы сложно.можно ли это
> сделать в несколько циклов?

Думаю да. Вот пример, вроде работает. Правда там нет символов, но есть словарь (вектор inverse), который задает соответствие между порядковым номером элемента при вводе и самим элементом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов>";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n, 0);
    vector<int> inverse(n, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int c;
        cin >> c;
        inverse [i] = c;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n) {
        v[i]++;
        for(int j = i; j--;) v[j] = v[j+1]+1;
        if(v[0] > n) i++;
        else { // комбинация допустима
            i = 0;
            cout << '{';
            for(int j = v.size(); j--;) 
                if(v[j] > 0) cout << inverse[v[j]-1] << (j?' ':'}');
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Результат для '1, 2, 3, 4':

```
Введите количество элементов>4
1 2 3 4
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
{1 2}
{1 3}
{1 4}
{2 3}
{2 4}
{3 4}
{1 2 3}
{1 2 4}
{1 3 4}
{2 3 4}
{1 2 3 4}
```

Comment: Спасибо,будем пробывать